# Xamarin Android Google SSO CustomUrlSchemeInterceptorActivity

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm developing a xamarin forms app with google SSO. The app is working back in June (which can redirect back to my app after google sign on using CustomUrlSchemeInterceptorActivity method).
However, when I tried the app yesterday, the google sign on wouldn't redirect back to the app (CustomUrlSchemeInterceptorActivity never got called).  Instead, it redirect back to google.com
Does anyone know if there is an update on the google side that prevent the redirect to happen?

Comment: You could check the suggestions in the links below. It would be helpful. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/155658/google-login-doesnt-redirect-back-to-app https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/175363/back-to-app-after-login-google-redirect-uri-xamarin-forms

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I decided to use the firebase method which is working fine